# How to pass a Javascript function in a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to pass a javascript function to a dynamically created div, like I am attempting below. If I replace the script string with an ordinary string this works, but is there a way to pass a JS script in createTextNode?

```
    newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newContent = document.createTextNode("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var pager = new Pager(3); pager.init(); pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); pager.showPage(1); </script>");
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
```

TIA

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there are much better ways to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to put the JavaScript dynamically inside the `<div>` tag? Whatever those functions do, they can do it from outside the `<div>`...

Comment: When you create new div like that, you need to attach that div somewhere, in the document object or any node or head etc.

Answer (score 1):

A `<script>` tag is not a text node.
You need to create a `<script>` element using `document.createElement`.

However, you should not do this, unless you're trying to load an external script file dynamically (eg, JSONP)

Answer (score 1):

```
var js=document.createElement('script');
  js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  js.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" var pager = new Pager(3); pager.init(); pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); pager.showPage(1); "));
  var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.appendChild(js);
  document.appendChild(newDiv);
```