# Putting a timed jQuery function on a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple little div being created when the user `mouseEnters` an `<h1>` tag. I'm creating the div with `prepend()`. Once this div is dynamically created, is there any way I could have a delayed fade out? Lets say 4 seconds after the div is created? Any help is much appreciated as always.

I checked out [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827033/how-to-pass-a-javascript-function-in-a-dynamically-created-div) but it's not helping.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
$('.sitename').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="mobile_pop">Available on All Mobile Devices</div>');
});//end mouseEnter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('.sitename').mouseenter(function(){
    var $div = $('<div class="mobile_pop" style="display:none;">Available on All Mobile Devices</div>');
    $(this).parent().prepend($div);
    setTimeout(function(){$div.fadeIn()}, 4000);
});
```

It simply registers with `setTimeout` a function fading in the div you created.

[Demonstration (the div is simply added to the body)](http://jsfiddle.net/8qfrR/)

Comment: Thank you so much dystroy! That totally helped and led me to where i needed to go! Thanks again